# Why java.awt.Image is not considered as java.awt.Component?

Tags: java, image, swing, inheritance, compiler-errors

I was trying to switch the content of Panel between Component and Image,
It works for the Component:

```
imgpanel.removeAll();
Component comp;
if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null) {
    imgpanel.add(comp);
}
```

Not for the Image:

```
btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buf.getFormat());
img = btoi.createImage(buf);
imgpanel.removeAll();
imgpanel.add(img);//The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Image)
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `java.awt.Image` is not considered as `java.awt.Component`?

An [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) extends `Object`. I.E.

- `Object`

  - `Image`

A [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) also extends `Object`. I.E.

- `Object`

  - `Component`

Since neither `Component` extends `Image`, nor `Image` extends `Component`, neither has an **is an** relationship to the other. OTOH both have the **is an** relationship only with `Object`. I.E. `Image` **is an** `Object` & `Component` **is an** `Object`.

> What should I do here?

Display the image in a `Component` designed to display images, such as (an `ImageIcon` in) a `JLabel`. So it might look like this:

```
panel.add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon(image) ) );
```

---

For more details on this concept, see [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in the 'Interfaces and Inheritance' section of the tutorial.